# increase timeout when running against remote grid

Tags: serenity-js

when running a test locally it succeeds, but when configuring a remote grid, it fails with

```
1) Scenario: Login - features/api.feature:10
   Step: When he enters his credentials - features/api.feature:13
   Step Definition: node_modules/serenity-js/src/serenity-cucumber/webdriver_synchroniser.ts:46
   Message:
     function timed out after 5000 milliseconds
```

How can I increase the timeout value?

Thanks & Ciao 
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Hi Stefan and thanks for giving Serenity/JS a try!

You have a couple of options here, depending on what is timing out.

As it's Protractor that's in charge of the timeouts, you'll need to look into your `protractor.conf.js` file.

Let's assume that your `protractor.conf.js` file looks more or less like the snippet below. I omit the Serenity/JS and Cucumber.js config for brevity as they're described at [serenity-js.org](http://serenity-js.org):

```
exports.config = {

    baseUrl: 'http://your.webapp.com',

    // Serenity/JS config
    framework: ...

    specs: [ 'features/**/*.feature' ],

    cucumberOpts: {
      // ...
    },

};
```

**0. Increasing the overall timeout**

To start with, you might want to increase the overall timeout of all the tests (for Protractor 5.0.0 the default value is set to **11s**).

To do this, add the `allScriptsTimeout` entry to your config:

```
exports.config = {

    allScriptsTimeout: <appropriate_timeout_in_millis>

    // ... rest of the config file
}
```

**1. Loading the page**

If the webapp under test is slow to load, you can tweak the `getPageTimeout` property (default set to **10s**):

```
exports.config = {

    getPageTimeout: <appropriate_timeout_in_millis>

    // ... rest of the config file
}
```

**2. A specific Cucumber step**

If a specific Cucumber step is timing out (which is most likely the case here, as Cucumber.js sets the [default value of the cucumber step timeout](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/timeouts.md) to **5s**), you can increase the timeout by changing the step definition (value in millis):

```
this.Given(/^When he enters his credentials$/, { timeout: 10 * 1000 }, () => {
    return stage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(
        Login.withTheirCredentials()
    );
});
```

Please note that in the above answer I'm assuming that you're using Serenity/JS with Cucumber to test an Angular app. If you're using a different web framework (like React), the test might also time out when Protractor is waiting for Angular to load.

If this describes your scenario, you might want to `ignoreSynchronization`:

```
exports.config = {

    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    }

    // ... rest of the config file
}
```

To find out more, check out the [Protractor documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) and the already mentioned [Cucumber docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/timeouts.md). I'll also add an article on [serenity-js.org](http://serenity-js.org) shortly to describe the different options so everything is in one place :-)

Hope this helps!

Jan

Comment: It works except `browser.ignoreSynchronization` that is deprecated.